# Every time I used {\textomega_0} the text after loses all the spaces after

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, greek, letters

I'm trying to add an omega with a sub scrip (omega null) and I used  {\textomega_0}

but it keeps giving me a result that looks like this

Whereω0isthenaturalfrequency

any ideas?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Tex-SE. Maybe a Minimal Working Example could help finding the cause of the issue you're experiencing.

Comment: You need math mode: `$\textomega_0$`

Comment: ...or `\textomega\textsubscript{0}`, depending on what you want, but in this case why not `$\omega_0$`? We definitely need a complete compilable example (small!).

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that what you really want is `$\omega_0$`. However, `\textomega\textsubscript{0}` and `$\upomega_0$` are also potential contenders.

E.g., you might write

```
... where $\omega_0$ is the natural ...
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textgreek} % for "\textomega" macro
\usepackage{upgreek}   % for "\upomega" macro
\begin{document}
\textomega\textsubscript{0} $\omega_0$ $\upomega_0$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, if I remember well there is also alphabeta package :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano - The chances that I'll be able to guess successfully  what exactly the OP may be trying to achieve are infinitesimal at best. That's also why I prefaced my suggestion with "I suspect that..."  :-)